# session id null php

Tags: php, apache, session

I have one test.php file.
I wrote two lines in it.

```
session_start();
echo session_id();
```

It gives me full session id when I run it from command line.

When I call this script from browser it outputs null. My web server is apache.

What is the problem?

Comment: Make sure the browser is accepting cookies. Also make sure there is no whitespace or blank line before the opening `<?php`

Comment: Do you get any errors? What is you *error\_reporting* configuration?

Comment: no there are no white spaces and browser also accept cookies

Comment: @gumbo There are no errors in my apache error.log. What do you mean by error reporting configuration?

Comment: If you have firefox, get the FireCookie extension and FireBug.  You can fully inspect the cookie traffic to the browser with FireCookie.

Comment: Try to run this php code without any white spaces at the beginning or ending in your file: **<?php session_start(); echo session_id(); ?>**

Comment: @dskanth no there are no white spaces

Comment: Check this directive setting in your php.ini file: 
session.use_cookies = 1. If 1, cookies are used to store sessions.

Comment: @Michael I have installed firecookie. The cookie sent by server has PHPSESSID and value is null

Comment: @dskanth I have installed firecookie and analyzed cookie. Please see my above comment

Comment: means your session is  destroyed, try in other browser

Comment: I have tried in chrome and it works perfectly.. How should I solve this for firefox??

Comment: @johngillow: does inserting `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` as first line give any clue?

Comment: restart firefox and clear the cache , btw which version of ff??

Comment: Maybe your Firefox has cookies disabled/blocked?

Comment: SOLVED I cleared all cache and removed one condition check if(isset($_POST)) which was above session_start(); The problem got solved. You can't even check condition before the session start. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session_start()` will return TRUE or FALSE if a session couldn't be started. Try to output that value

Answer (score 2):

try

```
print_r(session_id());
```

and what is the output